# subfigures don't appear in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, subfloats

I've a problem with using `subfigure`s. I want to list their caption in the list of figures. In my opinion this should not be a problem. I have read the `subfigure` package description http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/subfigure/subfigure.pdf allready but I can't get it.

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[
            fontsize = 12pt,
            paper = a4
            ]
            {article}

\usepackage{subfigure} % Um mehrere Bilder nebeneinander

\begin{document}

%-------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfigure[First.]{...}\qquad
\subfigure[Second figure.]{...}\\
\subfigure[Third.]{\label{3figs-c}...}%
\caption{Three subfigures.}
\label{3figs}
\end{figure}


%-------------------------------------------------------------


\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Another thing what is important maybe ist the `*.lof` File, although it looks quite complete to me:

```
\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Three subfigures.}}{1}
\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline {(a)}{\ignorespaces {First.}}}{1}
\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline {(b)}{\ignorespaces {Second figure.}}}{1}
\contentsline {subfigure}{\numberline {(c)}{\ignorespaces {Third.}}}{1}
```

I allready deleted all NOT- `*.tex` Files and recompiled the `*.tex` File.

I am using Windows, MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXmaker.

Please ask if you need more information!

I hope you can give me some input!

Comment: `subfigure` *is* obsolete; prefer `subfig` and its command `\subfloat` instead of `\subfigure`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you switch to the successor of `subfigure`, which is called `subfig` you can do that quite easily:

```
\documentclass[
            fontsize = 12pt,
            paper = a4
            ]
            {article}

\usepackage{subfig} % Um mehrere Bilder nebeneinander

\setcounter{lofdepth}{2} % we want subfigures in the list of figures

\begin{document}

%-------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfloat[First.]{...}\qquad
\subfloat[Second figure.]{...}\\
\subfloat[Third.]{\label{3figs-c}...}%
\caption{Three subfigures.}
\label{3figs}
\end{figure}


%-------------------------------------------------------------


\listoffigures
\end{document}
```

Comment: Notes for  people like me: "First." etc. are the captions of the subfloats - they are shown like "(a) First. (b) Second." and so on. An \includegraphics command can go directly inside the body of the subfloat (\subfloat[First]{\includegrapgics[height=40mm]{file.pdf}}"). The caption below all subfloats should be descriptive for all of them.

Comment: Oh, and to make \autoref work with subfloats, you can use \newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname} in the preamble.